# GCP Organization Administrator missing permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

My Google Cloud Platform user has the **"Organization Administrator"** role in IAM, but there are pages I go to that show the warning **"You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page"**.

What's the simplest way to give myself access to all resources?  I know the principle of least privilege is important, but this is only a test account, with nothing critical on it- I just want it working quickly.

Answer (score -1):

In IAM, **add the "Owner" role**.  This is bad security practice and should not be used for production accounts, but for a test account, it will quickly give you access.

Comment: Granting the IAM role **Owner** does not grant permissions for all resources. That role is legacy but does include the permissions required to grant yourself additional permissions for a specific project. Technically your answer is wrong based upon the question asked. There is no role that grants all permissions to all resources.

Comment: @Josh Please refer to the [IAM permissions reference](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/permissions-reference). This should be used for test purposes only; for production you should manage through SSH only.